# Screen noise interference Ubuntu kernel issue

Tags: boot, nvidia, noise

I use ubuntu 20.04 LTS and can't find a similar problem with solutions. I have hard time to find the good word to describe it.

All the packages are updated, I have the last nvidia driver 510.

I already reinstall the OS but the problem are still there. It appear only when the screen was in sleep or shutdown and I lauch the Os. After enter my password to unscripted my ssd the problem start.

They are no problem when I load a usb boot image of Ubuntu. When I first reinstall the OS the problem only appeared occasionally but after a reboot it's was gone. After 3 or 4 reboot it appear on every boot an the GUI is no more accessible.

The boot terminal (recovery) work fine.
I have take a picture for help, if you need me to run some diagnostic commands tell me which one and I can send the log.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_S_j55vtKcBF1Mn9ukgLT7aOBEMoz08/view?usp=drivesdk

Thanks  for your help.

Edit1: People with the same problem report on this page. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1952155 I downgrade the kernel version like indicates in the link and for now it works, so I will test before validate the problem résolution.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was with the kernel 5.13.xx. To resolve, we need to downgrade to the 5.11.xx which is normally already install and make this kernel the default by changing the boot in the Grub parameters files.